# TLS Upgrade for PayPal confusion - g5 root certificate

Tags: security, ssl, paypal, root

I'm upgrading a .NET 3.5 site that uses the PayPal API.  We need to update it for the upcoming TLS changes.  What confuses me is the SSLs:

> Discontinue use of the VeriSign G2 Root Certificate. In accordance
>   with industry standards, PayPal will no longer honor secure
>   connections that require the VeriSign G2 Root Certificate for trust
>   validation. Only secure connection requests that are expecting our
>   certificate/trust chain to be signed by the G5 Root Certificate will
>   result in successful secure connections.

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1766&expand=true&locale=en_US

I'm in the process of upgrading our site application to 4.5 to support TLS 1.2.  As well as this I've confirmed that the g5 certificate is a trusted root on the server.

Does this have anything to do with the SSL Certificate we have for the website itself?  Our current sites all have SSLs issued by 'RapidSSL SHA256 CA G3'.  Is that ok?  Or do we need to buy G5 certificates.  From the ones I've seen they're 10x the price (£500 pa)!!?

I'm guessing we just need to be able to see G5 as trusted and it's nothing to do with the website's SSL certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not have anything to do with your own certificate.

What PayPal says is the following:
If you don't trust the *G5 Root Certificate*, and thus used *VeriSign G2 Root Certificate* to validate PayPal's certificate, you won't be able to connect anymore in a trusted way.

That's it.